# How to read text file with variable row length in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv, textscan

I have of bunch of CSV files to read in Matlab. All of files has similar structure, except last field is optional. I.e. some files contain it, others are not.

Also files contain both textual and numeric fields, so [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) is not applicable.

Only alternative I know is [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html). Unfortunately, I can't find specifiers for optional fields.

I am looking at spec:

```
formatSpec = '%d%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%s%[^\n\r]';
```

and wish last `%s` be optional.

Comment: I think you can use [xlsread](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html). The function is meant to be used for excel sheets, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the strsplit function

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html

Answer (score 0):

To read a file line-by-line, you can use the function [`fgetl`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html). It reads one line, removes newline-characters and returns the line as a string. At the end of the file, a `-1` is returned.

You can then use the [`sscanf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html) to extract the data according to your format spec (including the `%s`). If your input data doesn't contain any string at the end, then the last field was empty.

```
fid = fopen('file.txt','r');
while 1
    line = fgetl(fid);
    if line == -1
        break;
    end
    A = sscanf(line,formatSpec);
    ...
end
```

You can then do whatever you need with `A`.

For example look at the following example:

```
line = '1 2.5 3.6 abc';
A = sscanf(line,'%d %f %f %s')

A =
    1.0000
    2.5000
    3.6000
   97.0000
   98.0000
   99.0000
```

The string will be `A(4:end)`. The string was empty if `isempty(A(4:end))`, that way you can store the data as you like, e.g. in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need the optional column, why not ignore the rest of the line by %*s and delimiter set to newline?

Comment: That's not a safe assumption to make, as "optional" doesn't imply "irrelevant".  It could very well be vital in cases where it is present.